# Is there a way to do a lowlevelkeyboardproc or lowlevelmouseproc locally instead of globally?

Tags: c#, windows

I've been having trouble with a certain problem. I've been disabling left and right mouse clicks for a particular application and my C# code looks like below...

My problem is that even though this works fine for disabling the mouse on a low level, isn't there a way in where I could disable it on a low level just for when the application is focused and therefor running?

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace GlobalLowLevelHooks
{
    public class MouseHook
    {

        public bool enabled = false;

        public delegate IntPtr MouseHookHandler(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
        public MouseHookHandler hookHandler;

        public delegate void MouseHookCallback(MSLLHOOKSTRUCT mouseStruct);

        #region Events
        public event MouseHookCallback LeftButtonDown;
        public event MouseHookCallback LeftButtonUp;
        public event MouseHookCallback RightButtonDown;
        public event MouseHookCallback RightButtonUp;
        public event MouseHookCallback MouseMove;
        public event MouseHookCallback MouseWheel;
        public event MouseHookCallback DoubleClick;
        public event MouseHookCallback MiddleButtonDown;
        public event MouseHookCallback MiddleButtonUp;
        #endregion

        public IntPtr hookID = IntPtr.Zero;
        public void Enable()
        {
            hookHandler = HookFunc;
            hookID = SetHook(hookHandler);
            enabled = true;
        }
        public void Disable()
        {
            if (hookID == IntPtr.Zero)
                return;

            UnhookWindowsHookEx(hookID);
            hookID = IntPtr.Zero;
            enabled = false;
        }
        ~MouseHook()
        {
            Enable();
        }
        private IntPtr SetHook(MouseHookHandler proc)
        {
            using (ProcessModule module = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule)
                return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, proc, GetModuleHandle(module.ModuleName), 0);
        }

        private IntPtr HookFunc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            // parse system messages
            if (nCode >= 0)
            {
                if (MouseMessages.WM_LBUTTONDOWN == (MouseMessages)wParam)
                {
                    return (IntPtr)1;
                }
                if (MouseMessages.WM_RBUTTONDOWN == (MouseMessages)wParam)
                {
                    return (IntPtr)1;
                }
                if (MouseMessages.WM_MBUTTONDOWN == (MouseMessages)wParam)
                {
                    return (IntPtr)1;
                }
                if (MouseMessages.WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK == (MouseMessages)wParam)
                {
                    return (IntPtr)1;
                }

            }
            return CallNextHookEx(hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }

        #region WinAPI
        private const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;

        private enum MouseMessages
        {
            WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201,
            WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202,
            WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200,
            WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A,
            WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204,
            WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205,
            WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x0203,
            WM_MBUTTONDOWN = 0x0207,
            WM_MBUTTONUP = 0x0208
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct POINT
        {
            public int x;
            public int y;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
        {
            public POINT pt;
            public uint mouseData;
            public uint flags;
            public uint time;
            public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
            MouseHookHandler lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: So the progress I've made so far...I got the windows threadid by using GetActiveWindow() and GetWindowProcessID() but when I pass it into SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, proc, GetModuleHandle(module.ModuleName), threadIdGoesHere).....it doesn't function properly...I'm wondering if this is due to the application having multiple threads or something? I am using Unity.

Comment: what doesn't function exactly? Please be more specific. Also, does the thread that *installs* the hook have a message loop? That is a requirement of these type of hooks. You didn't show how your app is using the hook